# Defining Arrays of type Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've looked at several examples and none quite match my problem. I'm trying to define an array of struct, no biggie, but when I do this in Xcode using pure C, I get a "Expected Expression" error that's driving me nuts.

The Code is as follows:

```
struct myType {
    unsigned char varName1;
    unsigned char varName2;
    unsigned char varName3;
};

struct myType myArray[10];

myArray[0] = {1,2,3}; // doesn't work at all despite many docs that say it will
myArray[1].varName1 = 1; // throws "expected expression" error
```

What am I doing wrong? I've checked for hidden characters, etc., nothing. It's clean and not imported into Xcode.

Comment: What happens if you take that second "`struct`" declaration away, and instead just simply do "`myType myArray[10];`"?  you might also want to put the keyword "`typedef`" in front of that first "`struct`".

Comment: @Mark; What compiler you are using? I'm sure this should work in GCC except the line `myArray[0] = {1,2,3}`

Comment: Compiler - Xcode 5.0.1 GNU99.

Comment: Doesn't like removing the second struct statement.

Comment: Okay, I got attribute level assignment working, but not entire struct assignment. So myArray[0].varName1 = 1; works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myArray[0] = (struct myType) {1,2,3};
```

Comment: Mario, you're the bomb. That was it. PFT! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

myArray[0] = {1,2,3} missing

";"

myArray[0] = {1,2,3};

Comment: extended initializer lists possible in c++11

Comment: Sorry, my code has the ;. Never convenient retyping into this editor.

Comment: @amald: The OP is using c, not c++, and what you said AFAIK won't work in c.